# WPF Code-Behind required namespaces

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, namespaces, code-behind

I'd like to keep my code clean and organized.
When creating a `.xaml` file (e.g. a view for your typical WPF MVVM pattern), Visual Studio automatically adds some namespaces for you in the Code-Behind for your View.  I'd like to remove redundant namespaces which aren't being used. My question is:
Which namespaces are save to remove, which aren't required for the underlying WPF mechanics?

For example, the `System.Window` namespace is obviously required since the Code-Behind class inherits the `Window` class. But which of the rest are safe to remove in a blank Code-Behind file like this one:
[image]

Reference for when the image is not working in the future:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DatabaseProject.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindowView : Window
    {
        public MainWindowView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe all you need is `System.Windows`. Just take them out one by one and see if it breaks anything. Also have to give a shout out to [Reshaper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It will remove the unused ones for you with alt + enter among a lot of other things. Not free though.

Comment: Visual Studio has [Organize Usings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514114.aspx) option.

Comment: When using IntelliSense *Remove Unused Usings* only `System.Windows` remains in this case. I'm guessing that Controls and Data aren't needed when using XAML for adding controls and bindings?

Comment: One word: **[Resharper!](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)** It cleans this mess up for you (ctrl-e-c) :) I can not live without it! For me there is no vs without R#, that is unless I'm coding c++ ;) Try it and you will be hooked for life!

Answer (score 4):

Delete all of them and then VS will underline which words are not recognizable, then use Ctrl + '.' for each to import. Resharper will automatically suggests missing namespace when mouse cursor is over text marked by red color. Then you need to click it and desired namespace will be added right away.

Comment: I prefer the *Organize Usings* suggested in Jesse Good's comment for simplicity.

Comment: +1 **[R# :)](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)** a full cleanup will also fix the issue as stated above. I suspect the user doesn't have it, because then it wouldn't be a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) has options to remove unused usings when a file is saved (its disabled by default) and to remove and sort usings for a whole project.

Also as you say you like clean organised code you might like the format document on save option too.